# How can I find the highest and lowest values in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a code that looks something like this for school:

```
 print ("Couple A Results")
coupleA = []
judges = 5
while len(coupleA) < judges:
    judge1 = input("Input Scores For Couple A in round 1: ")
    judge2 = input("Input Scores For Couple A in round 1: ")
    judge3 = input("Input Scores For Couple A in round 1: ")
    judge4 = input("Input Scores For Couple A in round 1: ")
    judge5 = input("Input Scores For Couple A in round 1: ")
    coupleA.append(judge1)
    coupleA.append(judge2)
    coupleA.append(judge3)
    coupleA.append(judge4)
    coupleA.append(judge5)
    print coupleA
print ("\nThese are the scores for couple A:")
print coupleA
```

I would like a separate piece of code to pull out the highest and lowest values from the list that had been inputted, and add the values in between. does anyone know how i would do this? Thanks

Comment: `print(max(int(i) for i in coupleA) + min(int(i) for i in coupleA))`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while` loop? Since `judges=5` and you are appending 5 things per loop, that `while` loop should only ever execute once.

Comment: @FilipMłynarski sorry if I didn't make it clear, but i would like the values in between the highest and lowest values to be added. For example if the values were 1,2,3,4,5 i would like 2,3,4 to be added?

Answer (score 3):

```
# convert to int because input returns string
values =(int(x) for x in coupleA)

# sort the values
values_sorted = sorted(values)

# sum all values except the first and the last one
sum(values_sorted[1:-1])
```

Comment: thanks, just what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: there was more than one couple eg coupleB, coupleC etc. which i found the sum of the middle numbers too, and now i need to find the highest value of all the new valueS! XD

Comment: you find the max and the min of a list as you see in the other examples with min() and max().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting all values, that could be computationally expensive, you could just subtract highest and lowest value from all values.

```
int_coupleA = [int(i) for i in coupleA]
between = sum(int_coupleA) - max(int_coupleA) - min(int_coupleA)
```

Comment: I am not brilliant at python and my brain is hurting after all this, but thanks for the comment!